# How to I use io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestEncoder finalizeRequest

Tags: java, netty, nio

I am using `netty 4.0` for a project. I encountered the following problem seeking answer:

In `io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestEncoder finalizeRequest()` method,
around `line 705`, the method returned `WrappedHttpRequest` if (the `realSize > ..chunkSize = 8k`),

So this returned Object is not `FullHttpRequest`, with NO content (`HttpContent`) member.
All other cases, the returned Object are subclass of `FullHttpRequest` with content.

How can I convert this to `WrappedFullHttpRequest` with content (body etc)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the multipart example it's shown there [1]

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadClient.java#L261

Comment: Thanks! I found the example very useful to send chunked vs non-chunked request.